# How to make progress bar for receiving response from API?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

while receiving data from API to flutter app it takes time to receive. How to make a progress bar to load until the JSON data is received to the flutter app and move to next Screen of the app.

I'm not using ListView.Builder. Instead I use it for texts, dropdown and other things also.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a FutureBuilder widget, as shown in the [cookbook for retrieving and displaying data](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) :

```dart
FutureBuilder<Album>(
  future: futureAlbum,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.title);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

This widget allows you to build your layout with information about the data your are loading and the status of the load itself.

For the `future:` parameter, give him your `http.get` request.

In the `builder:` param, give it an anonymous function that builds the content you want to display. In said closure, you can rely on the `snapshot` to know wether the data has finished downloading (`snapshot.hasData`) or if there was an error downloading (`snapshot.hasError`).
To display the progress bar you asked for, you can infer the status : if the snapshot has no data nor any error, therefore it is loading and you return you progress bar to the user.